# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultThreadFactory

Tags: java, netbeans, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultThreadFactory, while running code below. Please tell me what jar I'm missing. Using NetBeans and adding jars manually, no Maven.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Cassandra {

public static void main(String args[]){

  //Query
  String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE tp WITH replication "
     + "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};";

  //creating Cluster object
  Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build();

  //Creating Session object
  Session session = cluster.connect();

  //Executing the query
  session.execute(query);

  //using the KeySpace
  session.execute("USE tp");
  System.out.println("Keyspace 
}
}
```

I already have the following jars.

- guava-22.0-rc1.jar
- cassandra-driver-core-3.2.0
- metrics-core-3.0.2.
- netty-3.9.0.Final.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar

EDIT: I've added netty-all-4.0.4.Final.jar and got the following:

```
run:
13 [main] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility - Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
40 [main] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.Native - Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).
40 [main] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory - Using java.lang.System clock to generate timestamps.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.<init>(Lio/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor;)V
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:752)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1446)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:247)
    at cassandra.Cassandra.main(Cassandra.java:33)
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the full stack-trace or exception.

Comment: I just posted the full exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

netty-3.9.0.Final.jar should be in class/lib path

Answer (score 0):

You need to have netty-all-4.0.4.Final.jar in your classpath. It can be downloaded from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.4.Final

Comment: I added netty-all-4.04.Final.jar but I'm still getting an error

Comment: Seems like you are getting a different error now. Will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You have all the below jar. I have used maven and copy-dependencies plugin to extract all the jar

```
asm-5.0.3.jar
asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
asm-commons-5.0.3.jar
asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
asm-util-5.0.3.jar
cassandra-driver-core-3.2.0.jar
guava-19.0.jar
jffi-1.2.10-native.jar
jffi-1.2.10.jar
jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar
jnr-ffi-2.0.7.jar
jnr-posix-3.0.27.jar
jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
metrics-core-3.1.2.jar
netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.jar
netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.jar
netty-common-4.0.44.Final.jar
netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.jar
netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
```

Comment: I've added the jars you mentioned but got the same mistake

Comment: Did you add the listed jar into library and clean build ?